# What is the difference between 1|block:run and 1|(block:run)?

Tags: r, mixed-models, random-effects

Study design is an incomplete randomized block design. Fixed effects are maturity (covariate/continuous variable) and type (A, B, or C). There are 20 total samples with 7 of two types and 6 of one type. Samples were put into blocks with at least one of each type in the blocks. Two Blocks were analyzed over 4 runs, so Block is nested within Run. The model is `Y = Maturity + Type + Block-within-Run`, with `Block-within-Run` as a random effect. I accidentally coded it as `1|(Block:Run)` instead of `(1|Block:Run)` and got an error:

> Error: number of observations (=40) <= number of random effects (=48) for term (kernel_dm * type + 1 | (block:run)); the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable

So I just wondered what the difference was and what the | in this case is actually doing?

Comment: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#model-specification